# internet explorer, modernizr.js, respond.js, html5shiv.js, ie-7.js compatibility

Tags: media-queries, modernizr, twitter-bootstrap-3, ie7.js, respond.js

I have updated my code to latest ***Twitter Bootstrap v3***, and it has dropped support for older (ie7 or less) browsers, even ie8 / ie9 are not fully supported, so I am trying to use some third party plugin / scripts so I don't have to write IE specific css unless it's critical or necessary (***not*** worried about css3 shadows, rounded corners etc).

***modernizr.js*** I will be using this,
***respond.js*** (I think I will be using it as well for media queries support in older browsers)

now tell me if modernizr.js and respond.js can work together

also

I think ****html5shiv.js*** is not required as modernizr.js covers it (tell me if it does)? and also can I load alongside respond.js if modernizr.js doesn't provide html5 enhancement?

tell me if I still need to use ***ie9.js***? if yes with which combination?

As I want

a) Media queries support
b) Browser detection for css3 features support (which modernizr.js does well)
c) Would like my website(s) to work in IE browsers (***not*** worried about shadows, rounded corners etc, just bug's layout, float, etc)

so help me with this situation, oh and I also use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--<html class="js">-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

so tell me I need to do something with these as well to achieve my desired result (specially ***chrome-1*** should I be using it?

Thanks

****UPDATE:****
Since I asked this question, I am using this approach, I am using custom modernizr build without html5shiv, and I dropped `ie7.js` tried `ie9.js` same results (found it v. buggy instead of helping was causing issues), using [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) and separate [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) and it has been working for me fine since.

Now I also use this tag,
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`
dropped **chrome=1**

Comment: These are a lot of requirements that you want us to figure out for you. Have you tried anything at all? Have you started with the boilerplate that bootstrap provides (or the initializr project?) ... ? Have you tested anything in IE8 or above so we can see what results are you getting? Otherwise it is kind of tricky to answer your questions because it seems like you have a LOT of requirements that need to be met

Comment: If you care to read my requirements sincerely you see my question is simple and clear. So don't try to make it ambiguous. Point out a single line which is ambiguous or not clear?. If you don't know answer then don't comment and waste your time an energy. Thanks.